# How can I execute angular routing check the result and at the end cancel and not execute the navigation/routing

Tags: angular, routes

I'm like to write an validator that checks an String if its an valid route and also checks routing ends not in resulting one or mor special components written for 404.

So my question is is it possible to cancle the routing maybe if you use

```
this.router.navigate([{route}]).then(
   // doing some checks on router state
   // cancel navigation
)
```

Or may ther is also a better way you can check the result of routing.

Thank you for your feedback :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a router guard for that.Here's docs: [link](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay. 
Yes a guard could be possible you can also make somthing with the https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate Guard I found befor.
I was thinking there can be an easier solution because its just simply executing a route and check results.....

Comment: yeah but by this approach, you have to call the validator everywhere you call navigates and it will not work with routerLink. So I still think router guard is the best approach for this